# Disable '+' markup in org-mode on a by-file basis

Tags: org-mode

How do you escape the `+` to not mean strikethrough in a single file?
  For example, when typing

> use += 1 instead of ++

how can this not-be-strikethrough'ed?

Escaping the `+` with `\` as in `\+` works well, but it is not by-file.

Comment: Do you need to export this file into another format (html, tex etc), or do you just want to turn off the 'strikethrough' markup in the org buffer?

Comment: @Tyler: just the markup. Does the question need clarification?

Comment: Probably not, it looks like @fredtantini has an answer!

Comment: Often when writing code in an Org file, I wrap it in "=", even if the string has equals signs in it. (So in your case I would write "use =+== 1 instead of =++=".) This bypasses any formatting rules that might be inside the text, and makes it into a nice monospace font when exported.

Comment: @Archenoth: That is much more readable than escaping the `+` via ``\``. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behaviour is defined in the `org-emphasis-alist` variable.

To disable all markup, just write on your first line:

```
-*- org-emphasis-alist: nil -*-
```

To disable only the strike-through:

```
-*- org-emphasis-alist: (("*" bold) ("/" italic) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim) ("+" (:strike-through nil))); -*-
```

You can also use the syntax:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-emphasis-alist: (("*" bold) ("/" italic) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim) ("+" (:strike-through nil)))
# End:
```

(See [Specifying file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables))

`(("*" bold) ("/" italic) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim))` without the `("+" (:strike-through nil))` may work too.

Doing so, when you may have a warning when opening the file or reverting the buffer. Please refer to [safe file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html#Safe-File-Variables).

To disable the warning, when doing `M-x customize-variable safe-local-variable-values` click on `INS`, and add:

```
Key: org-emphasis-alist
Value: (("" bold) ("/" italic) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim))
```

Then `Apply` or `Apply and Save`.